# delete rows having time difference less than 2 hours of same eventid, venueid, startdate columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

Table: Test

```
id  eventid startdate           venueid
1   32  2023-03-16 19:30:00.000 3213934
2   32  2023-03-16 20:00:00.000 3213934
3   32  2023-03-16 20:30:00.000 3213934
4   32  2023-03-16 21:31:00.000 3213934
```

delete rows having time difference less than 2 hours for the same day, eventid, venueid

the delete commnad is

```
with cte as( 
    select 
        distinct t1.eventid
        , t1.startdate
        , t1.venueid 
        ,row_number() over (partition by t1.eventid, convert(date, t1.startdate), t1.venueid order by t1.startdate) as rn 
    from test1 t1 join test1 t2 
        on t1.id <> t2.id 
        and convert(date,t1.startdate) = convert(date,t2.startdate) 
        and t1.eventid = t2.eventid and t1.venueid = t2.venueid 
        where datediff(hh,t1.startdate,t2.startdate) < 2 
        order by t1.eventid) 
delete from cte where rn >1
```

after deletion, we should get only 2 rows of data (which are id's 1 & 4) because, the time difference of id's 1 & 4 is greater than 2 hours with same eventid and venueid but for other rows having id's as 2 & 3,time difference of id 2 & 3 is less than 2 hours with same eventid,venueid,date of startdate of  id 1

I tried by using below query, but unable to delete the required rows

```
select distinct t1.eventid, t1.startdate, t1.venueid 
from test t1
  join test t2 on t1.id <> t2.id  
              and convert(date,t1.startdate) = convert(date,t2.startdate)
              and t1.eventid = t2.eventid
              and t1.venueid = t2.venueid
where datediff(hh, t1.startdate, t2.startdate) < 2
order by t1.eventid
```

please provide solution for this

Comment: Besides that your query produces errors, even when correcting them your approach doesn't work at all https://dbfiddle.uk/m2szGqAu

Comment: by using your query, all rows are deleted from test table, table should have rows with startdate values 2023-03-16 19:30:00.000 and 2023-03-16 21:31:00.000, after deletion

Comment: as i said, you first need a cte that actually works, it is somewhat more comlicated with timeframes but your data only includes 4 dates and i am very unsure, which data should have rn 2 and abouve, i think you want only one date from a timeframe,

Comment: [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) "returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart **boundaries** crossed" (emphasis mine), e.g. `2023-01-02T06:50:00` and `2023-01-02T08:05:00` are two hours apart. Since each row in your sample data has a `startdate` within two hours of another row how do you determine which rows should be survivors, if any? "[D]elete rows having time difference less than 2 hours for the same day, eventid, venueid" ought to delete a pair of rows, no?

Answer (score 0):

try the windowed function `FIRST_VALUE()` like below. As it can't be used in where clause, it has to be in subquery:

```
/* delete from test where id in ( */
select id 
from(
   select 
      id
     ,[diffHour] = DATEDIFF(HOUR, 
                            FIRST_VALUE(startdate)
                            OVER(PARTITION BY eventid,venueid,convert(date,startdate) 
                            ORDER BY startdate), startdate)
   from test
  )a
  where diffHour>0 and diffHour<2
/*  )  */
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, this query actually works for my requirement. and thanks to all for the support.